# Android remote image ERROR

Tags: android, bitmap, connection

I want to Download An image from a remote server. But each time I get A nullpointer exception.

Method For Conencting to Server

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
    throws IOException
    {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();    
            Log.i("Download ", "Response: OK");
           }     
        else
            Log.i("Download ", "Response: NOK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
    }
    return in;    
}
```

Method For Creating Bitmap

```
private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {        
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;        
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        Log.i("Download ", "InputStream Available: " +in.available());
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        Log.i("Download ", "Bitmap: " +bitmap.describeContents());
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;                
}
```

The null pointerException is thrown when I decodeStream, but when I use a different URL it works.

I run Apache on port 90. could this also have an effect if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this I hope is working.

to connect with ftp use this code

```
public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;

public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
                              String password, int port)
    {
        try {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
            // connecting to the host
            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

            // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                // login using username & password
                boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
                return status;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
        }

        return false;
    }
```

to download file use this code

```
public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath)
{
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(desFilePath);;
        status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
        desFileStream.close();

        return status;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to Respond But , I figured out the problem. It works when I upload a PNG image and not a JPEG image. But I used and your code and it does upload.

Comment: @Sims if the answer is helpful to you than You can check a right arrow at the left side of a answer.